# MySQL Update two rows from 2 columns

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to simplify these two statements into one?

```
UPDATE items
SET D1 = 'AAA'
WHERE D1 = 'BBB'

UPDATE items
SET D2 = 'AAA'
WHERE D2 = 'BBB'
```

I want to set D1 to AAA ONLY IF D1 is BBB, and D2 to AAA  only if D2 is BBB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the most efficient way you can do this in one statement:

```
UPDATE items
SET D1 = IF(D1 = 'BBB', 'AAA', D1),
    D2 = IF(D2 = 'BBB', 'AAA', D2)
WHERE D1 = 'BBB' OR D2 = 'BBB';
```

For the best performance, make sure you have separate indexes on `D1` and `D2`.  The query planner can do an index merge in this case.  Don't use only a multi-column index, or the query planner will have to fall back on a table scan.

Comment: Have you ever seen index merge in real life?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Have I seen `EXPLAIN` indicate that it would do one?  Yes.

Comment: yep, that was the question. Because I could reproduce this behaviour

Comment: @zerkms The query planner uses statistics about the involved table(s) when deciding how to execute a query.  If the table's contents all fit on one page, then a table scan will be no slower than an index merge, and will probably be faster.  You'd likely need several hundred, possibly thousand, rows before the planner would decide to use any indexes, because using indexes for just a handful of rows is slower than just scanning the whole table.

Comment: I know that ;-) I made experiments with 1m+ tables

Comment: @zerkms Then perhaps the query you were using couldn't possibly have made use of an index merge, or perhaps you were lacking the requisite indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if, and setting the column to it self if row dosn't meet the criterium

```
UPDATE items
SET
  D1 = IF(D1 = 'BBB', 'AAA', D1),
  D2 = IF(D2 = 'BBB', 'AAA', D2)
WHERE
  D1 = 'BBB' OR
  D2 = 'BBB'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE items SET D1 = 'AAA', SET D2 = 'AAA' WHERE D1 = 'BBB' AND D2 = 'BBB'
```

or depending on what you want to achieve:

```
UPDATE items SET D1 = 'AAA', SET D2 = 'AAA' WHERE D1 = 'BBB' OR D2 = 'BBB'
```